# Types Mismatch error on range value, can't figure out why

Tags: excel, vba

So Every time I run my code I get the Types Mismatch error and I can't find what to change into what in order to run it properly. Even though this might still not entirely Solve the greater problem which is how to formulate my question into the vba code, but first things first. How to get this line of code without errors:

```
Range("I" & r & ":" & "I" & B).Value = Range("I" & r & ":" & "I" & B).Value + 1
```

Where r = the current row the code is checking ( 5 to 44)
and B is the last row the code can check ( 44) 
All I want this line to do is to add one to the already existing value of the cell (which is 0 if nothing is done in that row or a formula if conditions are met, this formula will make a value from 1 to 40)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this the way you are doing -> you cannot add a number to a range of cells at once. You must add the number to one cell at a time.

Try this:

```
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = r To B
        Range("I" & i).Value = Range("I" & i).Value + 1
    Next
```

To handle formulas:

```
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = r To B

        Dim numberToAdd As Integer
        numberToAdd = 1

        If Range("I" & i).HasFormula Then
            Range("I" & i).Value = Range("I" & i).Formula & "+" & Trim(Str(numberToAdd))
        Else
            Range("I" & i).Value = Range("I" & i).Value + 1
        End If

    Next
```

Comment: Thanks a LOT that actually removed the error, though now it does not add the 1 to the result of the formula as I hoped it would... it just adds 1 to the next cell that has no formula yet...
Thanks anyways this helped a lot!

Comment: In that case, see edited answer above. 
Added example for handeling formulas.